# Range of a continuous linear mapping

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to show that the range of the linear map

$T:(\ell^1,\parallel .\parallel_1)\to (\ell^2,\parallel .\parallel_2)$ defined by $Tx=x$ is not closed.

I considered a sequence $(x^{(n)})$ in $\ell^1$, where $x^{(n)}=(1,\dfrac{1}{2},...,\dfrac{1}{n},0,0,...)$. Can this sequence converge to $x=(1,\dfrac{1}{2},...,\dfrac{1}{n},...)$? If so, we can show that $x\notin (\ell^1,\parallel .\parallel_2)$. Please help!

Comment: Why do you have $\ell^2$?

Comment: I want to show that $x\in \ell^2$ but not in $\ell^1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your example works. You have
$$
\|x^{(n)}-x\|_2^2=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^2},
$$
which will become arbitrarily small for big enough $n$. So $\{x^{(n)}\}$ is convergent in $\ell^2$. But $x\not\in\ell^1$, so it does not belong to the range of $T$.